# What qualifies a paper/dissertation to received the status 'published'

Tags: publications, online-publication

This is for a master's level, if a department decides to publish students' dissertations, does that qualify to be named as a published paper? or does it have to be a journal with certain impact factor?

**Edit**: if online publications are considered ok, can they be added to a resume in 'publication' sections?

Comment: I think the difference lies in the peer-review process. Just because something is made available (or "published") doesn't give it any academic weight.

Comment: @Landric So unless it gets peer reviewed, it would not qualify for that status?

Comment: I wouldn't like to say with certainty (which is why I haven't made this an answer); however, certain types of publications (such as Tech Reports) are more often published by an academic institution rather than a journal. It also depends what you want to use it for; you might not be able to use it as a citation, but I think it would be fair to include it on your resume.

Comment: @Landric great, I'll leave the question up in hope of getting more comments on this.

Comment: A MSc thesis residing on an university's repository is not a peer-reviewed publication. Period.

Comment: ...but it **is** a publication.  Period.

Comment: Interesting debate between JeffE and Alexandros

Comment: There really is no debate. @JeffE is right because a MSc thesis is a publication and thus can be cited. On the other hand, so does a blog or an manual for a vehicle or the website of an online tool. I am also right because a MSc thesis is not a peer-review publication as a paper accepted in a journal or a conference.

Comment: I was just interested in the academic sense, I know many things would qualify to be considered publications.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The exact meaning of the word "publication" is dependent on context.  In some contexts, it might be understood to include only articles accepted in peer-reviewed journals or conference proceedings.  (Impact factor is not usually a consideration here.)  In other contexts, it might also include books, dissertations, lecture notes, arXiv preprints, and other documents that have been made publicly available.

So whether a dissertation should be "named as a published paper" depends on your audience.

For academic CVs, people often create two sections: one that lists peer-reviewed publications, and another that lists non-peer-reviewed writings.  This removes any ambiguity.  A master's dissertation would go in the non-peer-reviewed section.

If you are writing a resume for the business world, standards might be different.  http://workplace.stackexchange.com might be a better place to ask about that situation.

Comment: Indeed I am targeting academia. Thanks for the concise answer.

Answer (score 6):

It is published according to the usual, dictionary definition of "publish", but that is the wrong question. A better question, is "Does this publication count towards my list of requirements for X?" where X might be:

- tenure
- promotion
- hiring for research-only positions

In the academic tenure context, there will be a list of publication types that count towards your tenure case. These often include peer-reviewed journal articles, peer-reviewed conference papers, and books. The requirements might be more strict like first-author papers in one of a small list of conferences.

A master's thesis usually wouldn't count for much in this context. It might have been helpful to your hiring case as a tenure-track professor, but even that is unlikely. It is certainly an interesting piece of a PhD admissions package for someone who decided to get a master's and PhD at different institutions.